# Can SYSTEM_INFO::dwActiveProcessorMask change while my process is running?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cpu

I'm curious about something. Can [dwActiveProcessorMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958(v=vs.85).aspx) member of the `SYSTEM_INFO` struct change after my service starts running (on Windows)? If not, I'd cache it when it is initializing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is reasonable to assume that it could change. See, for example, [this description of dealing with dynamic partitioning and how to code and test for correctness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff562404(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score -3):

Of course not, `dwActiveProcessorMask` is set during the hardware-detection phase on boot, it may only change once the hardware is changed. If you read the value during your application initialization-phase you will always be good.